# Preventing accidental production deployments in ansible

Tags: ansible, environments

Last night I ran a playbook from a wrong branch that referenced an old inventory file with old IPs for each server, and deployed a dev build to a production machine. What would be a a good practice to avoid such mistake from happening in the future? How can I isolate environments better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best practice is to [separate production and staging(testing) inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#staging-vs-production).  See [Staging vs Production](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#staging-vs-production).

> This way you pick with -i what you are targeting.

To make it more robust you might want to clone a separate structure for production and restrict access to it. Pull from staging before deploying to production.

In detail, this would mean to 1) put the [directories](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_best_practices.html#directory-layout) into git, 2) make sure staging is committed, pushed and merged, and 3) then pull to the production and deploy. The [workflow](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Branching-Workflows) is up to you.

Comment: I targeted dev, but some of the machines in dev inventory had prod IPs. I think there was reshuffling by the infra team a while back and the branch i was on used that. I am looking for a fool proof ,solution that will exclude such possibility.

Comment: Sure, I've updated the answer. Please, update the question (you're able to edit it)  and delete the comment to make the thread clear.